# Define Database Constraints in both Model and Database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have been trying to define database relations and constraints in both model and Database? 
Currently it is throwing error.
I have two tables 'posts' and 'comments'. And I have defined the relationship in my models as follows:

```
class Comment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

and

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Am I missing something ? Anyone please help.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: It would be brilliant if you would tell us the error you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all those empty values and they may be messing things up. You should only need:

Comment.php

```
class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Post'
    );

}
```

and

```
class Post extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment'
    );

}
```

Also, let us know the error as currently we have nothing to go on...